# from kivymd.properties import StringProperty

Tags: python, kivy

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola comunidad soy nuevo en el ambiente. Estoy creando un clon de Facebook con KIVY pero me surge un problema cuando pongo "from kivymd.properties import StringProperty".
Cuando pongo kivymd.properties me lo toma como MissingImports. Tengo todas las librerias y dependencias pero no logro pasar de esta parte.

Hello community I am new to the environment. I am creating a Facebook clone with KIVY but I have a problem when I put "from kivymd.properties import StringProperty".
When I put kivymd.properties it takes it as MissingImports. I have all the libraries and dependencies but I can not get past this part.

Comment: no sé si existe properties en kivimd si lo está en kivi así que: from kivy.properties import StringProperty debe funcionar

Comment: Perdon me equivoque es "kivy" sin "md"

Comment: el problema es que pongo 
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty 
y no reconoce "kivy.properties"

Comment: ¿te reconoce kivi? vamos por lo básico: import kivy

Comment: Sisi, todos los import. Incluso pasa poder importar StringProperty pude hacerlo desde "from kivy.app import StringProperty" de otra manera no me funciona. Y ahora que estaba finalizando el proyecto debía hacer "from kivy.properties import StringPropery, NumericProperty" y no funciona kivy.properties

Comment: pues habría que ver que versión de python estás usando y el idle, lo probaste directamente desde el shell de python?

Comment: estoy con la version actual de python, y prove con el shell de python, con pycharm, cmd, y con WSL